# Xamarin Forms: GeolocatorPlugin - DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, geolocation

I'm using GeolocatorPlugin, plugin by James Montemagno, with Xamarin Forms and sometimes it gives me the following error:
*GeolocatorImplementation.GetAddressesForPositionAsync (Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position, System.String mapKey) Java.IO.IOException: dhun: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.670355385s.*
and the app crashes.
How can I control the error?

Comment: that plugin is deprecated in favor of Xamarin Essentials.  Regardless, have you tried simply trapping the exception?